# Bash forcing newline in single line command

Tags: bash

When trying to open a new file with a long filename in vim

```
$ vim long_file_name
```

Bash keeps giving me a newline when I press enter

```
$ vim long_file_name [enter]
>
>
```

I'm wondering why this is, and how I can avoid getting this newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a single, double, or backquote or some other "start" character sequence in the filename that you forgot to escape, so bash is waiting for you to finish typing the rest of the command line.

Comment: Actually, the filename end with .tex without any trailing characters.
    vim long_file_name.tex [enter]

Comment: That invalidates my answer how?

Comment: No, you're right; I forgot to escape a single quote in my filename. :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement Ignacio's answer, the prompt `>` is called the secondary prompt (set by environment variable `PS2`).

`bash` displays `PS2` when it needs more input to complete a command (started interactively from prompt `PS1`) e.g. when you put a only a single/double quote on the command in `PS1` prompt or use a backslash escape at the end.

From `man bash`:

> PS2    The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used as
>   the secondary prompt string.  The default is ``> ''.